# jQuery and AJAX?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm making a simple form which has 5 `input` elements for parts of an address. I use jQuery to build and send an AJAX request to a PHP file on my server. For some reason my jQuery is not properly able to read the values from my `input` elements. What could be wrong?

**Here is my jQuery:**

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    $('#BBRequestBox').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');

    alert('Info: ' + $('#name').val() + ' ' + $('#street').val() + ' '
                   + $('#city').val() + ' ' + $('#state').val() + ' '
                   + $('#zip').val() + ' ');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./bbrequest.php",
        data: {
            name:   $('#name').val(),
            street: $('#street').val(),
            city:   $('#city').val(),
            state:  $('#state').val(),
            zip:    $('#zip').val()
        },
        success: function(msg){
            $('#BBRequestBox').html('<p>' + msg + '</p>');
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            $('#BBRequestBox').html('<p> There\'s been an error: '
                + errorThrown + '</p>');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**Here is my HTML:**

```
                        <div id="BBRequestBox">
                            <form action="#">
                                <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="textbox" />
                                <label>Street:</label><input type="text" name="street" id="street" class="textbox" />
                                <label>City:</label><input type="text" id="city" class="textbox" />
                                <label>State:</label><input type="text" id="state" class="textbox" />
                                <label>Zip:</label><input type="text" id="zip" class="textbox" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Send Me a Bitachon Builder!" id="submitButton" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

**EDIT:**

Live example at [Bitachon.org/new](http://bitachon.org/new). Click  on "Get the Bitachon Builder. (Leftmost footer link)

Comment: @MikeRobinson  It alerts undefined for each variable.

Comment: The alert works fine when I use it: http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/cKmrT/

Comment: @Damien-at-SF - Yes it works fine by me too.

Comment: @Moshe, so just to make sure, the alert line doesnt work on your page but does work in the jsfiddle I set up? If thats the case, do you have an online example where we can see the alert fail?

Comment: @Moshe, can you link the online example...? :) difficult to see whats wrong when the jsfiddle with your code works :P

Comment: @Damien-at-SF - I did link it already.

Comment: @Moshe, sorry, I saw the link, both Andy and I posted the answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so because you are replacing the contents of the request box with your loading image, you are actually removing the  tags that contained data PRIOR to processing them... as such, when your jQuery function looks for the elements, it cannot find them and for that matter their values...

If you remove this line: `$('#BBRequestBox').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');` it will work...

<del>I'm working on a way to get that loading image there in the mean time</del> <- Looks like you already have the solution for that below :P

Comment: A local array to hold the values should be created and then the image placed.

Comment: nah, everyone overlooked it :) just one of those things :D glad its fixed!

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the html of your requestbox with the loading gif.
So the inputs don't exist anymore when you're trying to access them.

```
$('#BBRequestBox').html('<img src="images/loading.gif" />');
```

you could do something like this:

```
$('#BBRequestBox').prepend('<img src="images/loading.gif"/>').find('form').hide();
```

Comment: +1. This looks to be it. The JSFiddle linked to in the comments doesn't include the `#BBRequestBox` div, so it didn't catch this.

Comment: Interesting solution. I'm using the array for now though, unless there is a valid reason not to. (I'm open to an explanation why this is better.)

Comment: It's just an example for an easy fix by only having to change one line:)

Answer (score 1):

It should work.  My guess is the input elements don't exist when you are trying to attach your click handler.  Try wrapping your js in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Your stuff goes here
});
```

Comment: Good call, jsfiddle takes care of all of that for you, thats why my link worked :) +1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your code isn't working, but I suggest looking into the [serialize() jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead of manually constructing your data object.. It will reduce the amount of code you need to write, which could eliminate your bug.

And we all know that [coding smaller](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/code-smaller.html) is a good idea. :-)